# Converting speed variance to time variance

Tags: experiment-design

I'm doing a design of experiments unit. I came up with prediction equations that predict the speed of a robot completing tracks of different types. The prediction equations give the settings for the best speed of the robot (m/s) for any particular track. The equations give a prediction for the average and the variance, in m/s, because that is the data that was fed into the regression to come up with the prediction equations.

I am wondering how to convert my variance in m/s to seconds. E.g. say there is a particular track that my prediction equation suggests the best average speed I will get will be 0.5 m/s. And I know the track is 2 meters. So I will expect on average, my time to complete the track will be 2/0.5 = 4 s. Say I also have a predicted speed variance. I.e. my prediction equation gives a speed variance of 0.01 m/s (actually, it is standard deviation) for the track. How would you go about converting that variance to seconds?

Comment: This ends up being a convolution. If you assume that the distributions are normal then the final distribution will be $N(0.5 \cdot 4,\sqrt{0.01^2 \cdot 4})$. This only works for normal (independent) distributions, for more general distributions an approximation can be obtained.

Comment: It is not clear that expected time is 4 seconds.  Suppose your average speed is equally likely to be 0.4, 0.5 or 0.6 m/s with a mean of 0.5.  Then your  expected time for a 2 metre track is about $\frac13(\frac{2}{0.4}+\frac{2}{0.5}+\frac{2}{0.6}) \approx 4.11$ seconds.  This effect will typically be smaller if the variance or standard deviation is also small

Comment: Thanks user2974951 and Henry

Comment: Does any of this answer your question?

Comment: Hi @user2974951. I think what I sought was a bit simpler. In my report I wrote this:
Letting ‘a’ be the conversion factor from m/s to s (track length divided by predicted average speed), then predicted lap times in seconds are obtained by the following theorems from Pishro-Nik, 2016:
* theorem 3.2
* theorem 3.3
https://github.com/casrou/ProbToPdf/blob/master/Introduction%20to%20Probability%2C%20Statistics%2C%20and%20Random%20Processes%20-%20Hossein%20Pishro-Nik.pdf
(the official website for the book is a bit slow at the moment)